# Want to have a column with images in a datatable; it works with URL but does not work with local paths

Tags: r, image, shiny, png, dt

I am trying to add a column with only images into a datatable.
However, this is the best I got so far:

[image]

I'm not a expert in programming so I've been looking on the web in order to find a solution but nothing seems to work. I've tried solutions like the one in [How to embed an image in a cell a table using DT, R and Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671958/how-to-embed-an-image-in-a-cell-a-table-using-dt-r-and-shiny) , [How to place an image in an R Shiny title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182535/how-to-place-an-image-in-an-r-shiny-title) , [Adding logos/images to the side of a data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871295/adding-logos-images-to-the-side-of-a-data-table) and others...

This is a shiny app and the images are stored locally in my computer. I don't know why so many posts refer to a **www** folder because I thought that RStudio would look to the directory set with `setwd()`, which I had done. But I even created this **www** folder with the images and I put my **app.R** inside (also tried with it outside), but nothing works. However, if I input an URL, the image is displayed, but I really need to do it with local paths for now. Maybe later I will use the URL but this is bugging me off and I would really appreciate a solution (excuse me for being such a noob). I've also seen somewhere that it could be solved by pressing 'Run App' instead of selecting the whole code and run it, but that didn't work as well.

To finish, here is the relevant part of the code (data is already loaded into RStudio):

```
library('shiny')
library('shinydashboard')
library('tidyverse')
library('data.table')
library('plotly')
library('DT')

setwd("C:/Users/directory/with/images/www")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Visuals"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Units table w/ links", tabName = "tabU", icon = icon("table"))
)
tabItem(tabName="tabU",
              fluidRow(
                box(
                  DT::dataTableOutput("data"),
                  width=12),
              ))
)
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

df <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(
      Name = readUnits$label,
      Icon=c('<img src="img1.png" height="52"></img>',
             '<img src="img1.png" height="52"></img>',
             '<img src="img2.png" height="52"></img>',
             '<img src="img3.png" height="52"></img>',
             '<img src="img4.png" height="52"></img>',
             '<img src="img4.png" height="52"></img>',
             '<img src="img5.png" height="52"></img>',
             '<img src="img6.png" height="52"></img>',
             '<img src="img7.png" height="52"></img>',
             '<img src="img7.png" height="52"></img>',
             '<img src="img8.png" height="52"></img>',
             '<img src="img9.png" height="52"></img>'),
      Actions = shinyInput(actionButton, 12, 'button_', label = "Linked to", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' ),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
      row.names = 1:12
    ))
    
    
    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable(
      df$data, server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none'
    )

...
```

This should be the only part of the code that is relevant (other tabs are not included, as well as server code), so don't mind if some parentheses is missing or something like that. I would simply like to have a proper way of displaying the local images in the column.
So, can someone please help me?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If your images are in **www** then you must set its parent directory as the current directory.

Comment: Also tried that, still no success. There can be more folders besides **www** in the parent directory, right?

Comment: Have you saved the app file in the parent directory of the **www** folder? (you have to)

Comment: Yes, still no image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, that doesn't work. This way works, with the images in the **www** subfolder:

```r
render <- c(
  "function(data, type, row){",
  "  if(type === 'display'){",
  "    var tag = '<img src=\"' + data + '.png\" width=\"100\"/>';",
  "    return tag;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

df <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(
  Name = readUnits$label,
  Icon=c("img1",
         "img1",
         "img2",
         .........),
  Actions = shinyInput(
    actionButton, 12, 'button_', label = "Linked to", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\", this.id)'
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  row.names = 1:12
))

output$data <- renderDT({
  datatable(
    df$data, 
    selection = 'none',
    options = list(
      columnDefs = list(
        list(targets = 2, render = JS(render))
      )
    )
  )
}, server = FALSE)
```

Comment: With that solution - still no images and the buttons dissapeared (photo above)

Do I need to change the output in the ui because of **renderDT**? And I've set the wd as the one where the **app.r** is located (correct?)

Comment: Ah yes I forgot the buttons. But have you changed `Icon` to `c("img1", "img2", ......)`? This works for me.

Comment: @EduardoRocha I forgot to tag you in my previous comment...

Comment: OMG, it works if I click on 'Run app' but not if I select the code and execute it...

Thank you very much for the help! :)

Comment: But how can I fix the buttons now? ahahah